# Using Python 3.9 and uninstalling an older version of PIL and replacing with the most current version

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, python3

I have downloaded Python 3.9 and the latest version of PIP or so I thought.  I am trying to work with PIL, but I keep getting invalid syntax error.  I did some research to uninstall PIL and reinstall with the latest, but something must have changed with the newest versions, because every suggestion I read and tried didn't work.

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details.

Comment: @guiverc chuck lee is a new contributor so it's likely that he is using Ubuntu 20.04, 21.04 or 21.10, all of which are "vanilla" versions with respect to my answer.

Comment: I agree @karel, but I don't know how to respond. FYI: the close-vote wasn't me; I commented my 2c & moved on..

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 and later has the python3.9 package in its default repositories. It can be installed by `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3.9` and then install PIL with `sudo apt install python3-pil` . Installing both of these packages from the default Ubuntu repositories simplifies package management.

If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 keep Python 3.8 as the default Python 3.x version and switch to Python 3.9 only when necessary using `update-alternatives`. After you are done using Python 3.9 you can switch the it back to the default Python 3 version.

- List installed versions of Python: `update-alternatives --list python`
- Switch between Python versions: `update-alternatives --config python`

  From the terminal command-line Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

Getting the latest version of PIL working in Ubuntu 18.04 is more convoluted. Please comment if you are using Ubuntu 18.04 and I'll revise this answer. If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 I guess you want to install PIL with `sudo pip3 install pil`, right?